# When I change into edit mode from the default cube it stays in wire frame mode

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm using Blender 2.83 and I change to edit mode it stays in wire frame mode no matter that it is in solid mode. The mesh does not show up. I turned off wire frame mode in object properties and still no mesh. When I hit f key nothing happens. But I switch back to object mode the mesh shhows up.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a picture of the object? Is it showing up as wire frame or not at all?

Comment: It shows up like wireframe mode and I can change into vertex mode but still no mesh. But it shows up in object mode

Comment: I just opened another blender start screen and it works

Comment: But when I open the screen that I have my project in  I open up a fresh cub and samee problem